# Extract all CSS rules set that have a certain rule

Tags: php, html, css, fonts

I was asked to change the font used in my client's website. they are using a commercial template.

I searched in the stylesheet files and saw that there are almost 400 occurrences spread in 12 different files for "font-family", I need to override them all somehow.

I don't want to use the universal rule (*) since it feels like it can cause unexpected results (like preventing me to use a second font-family)

Any Ideas?

I thought maybe I can use some tool/software to extract the entire rule in each of files into a separate file(s) and than I could easily copy them and search-replace the font family, is there such a tool/software?

I could also use PHP to look in those files and search/replace on run time  but it seems like bad practice to run this on every page load.

Please advise, what would you do?

** MORE INFO: **

I don't want to edit the original files or copy them entirely. I want to extract just the rule name and the font-family attribute and value.

Example:

```
.some_rule {color: red;font-size: 16px;**font-family: 'whatever';**float: right;}
```

To become / To extract:

```
    .some_rule {**font-family: 'whatever';**}
```

Then I can copy only this part to my override.css file (for example).
Thanks!

** UPDATE **
I'm sure there is a nicer way to do it, but for my needs, just to get things done in a few lines of code, this is what I did:

1. copied the files to temp directory
2. formatted them so EVERYTHING will be in a new line (declaration, attr + value, closing curly brace);
3. run the php code I wrote - http://codepad.org/D2YOKYJ5

This snippet creates a new file (or write to an existing one) with only what I needed.

Comment: can't you load a new stylesheet after the theme's stylesheet that overrides the old `font-family` rules?

Comment: I'd use mass replace for starters, but the SASS suggestion is the way to go

Comment: _“almost 400 occurrences spread in 12 different files”_ – picking those out sounds like at most an hour’s worth of work … so give it to an intern :p

Comment: On a more serious note – I’d probably rather go about this client-side, using JavaScript … starting with a loop over `Document.styleSheets`, and from there to looking at the individual `CSSStyleRule`s to see if they are specifying that font family … and if so, the `selectorText` goes into the list.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a replace action that a simple editor could do in a matter of minutes.

But you might consider migrating to SCSS or another CSS precompiler.

The advantage of SCSS (over SASS, for instance), is that it's completely CSS compatible, so you can just rename all CSS files to SCSS, configure an SCSS compiler, and you're up and running.

Once you've got that, you can start replacing the font family with variables or mixins, and gradually you can add more and more structure to the CSS files by refactoring certain parts of it.

If you don't want to modify the CSS at all (since it is a commercial template, and you may want to be able to download updates), you can collect all selectors for the font and make a new CSS file with them, overriding just the fonts for those specific selectors.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself right...I dont want to edit the original file. I dont want to copy the entire rule. I want to extract just the rule set and keep the font-family rule itself.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid you'll have to use manual labor to collect those rules from all the files.